# Crystal report summary depending on another column

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

[Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUyIp.png)

[image]
Hi, i am new to crystal reports but a fast learner.

I need to make a report, that shows the price of specific maintenance during a month.

The important thing is that the Total values are correct

As you see the "arbejdsordre" can appear multiple times because on the same column it has different "titel" the different "titel" has different "planlagt tid" but the same "Omkostninger"

I need to tell crystal report to only calculate "omkostninger" for "arbejdsordre" one time when "arbejdsordre appears several times.

how can i do this?

Best regards
André

Comment: where is "omkostninger" displayed on your image?

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the Group Expert and then group your report data by Omkostninger you should be able to accomplish your goal.

Display the value for "Omkostninger" in the Group Header, and then display the different "titel" and "planlagt tid" in the details section or any other group header section that is a lower level grouping than Omkostninger.

This will allow you to display each unique value for Omkostninger once and only once on the report, with all of the other data for each Omkostninger value displayed in the details.